# interesting situation in c++

Tags: c++, netbeans

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  std:: cout<<"hello world";
  std::cout<<"i am surprise<"<<std::endl;
    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

It is very strange because I am using netbeans in Ubuntu 10.04 and run this code.  What happens here really makes me surprised; every line of code is marked with red line.  For example:

- first line indicates that it can't find indicator iostream or can't find file iostream;
- second line can't find file stdlib;
- third line  unable to resolve identifier std and so on,
- but it compiles fine and shows me the result "hello world i am surprise"

Please explain why is this happens?

Comment: This is a problem with netbeans (or its configuration); it's not really about C++ as a language.

Comment: Please use proper punctuation. The IDE sees different source files than your compiler.

Comment: I just can't read questions phrased like this. Did you proofread before you post it?

Comment: Not everyone on SO is a native English speaker.  I try to do my part by editing questions for grammar/spelling.

Comment: On a side note, I'd recommended using `KDevelop` for C++ if you're on linux. I've found that eclipse and others do a terrible job at C++

Answer (score 1):

Your IDE's "on the fly" correction tool might not be working correctly (because of bad settings or because fo bugs). I'm guessing it just don't have the access to the default includes.

Your compiler is a separate tool that have access to the includes so it will compile fine anyway.

Try to set the settings correctly or turn the underlining off, or even switch to a better IDE for C++.

Answer (score 1):

The paths for "Code Assistance" are configured separately from your compiler includes. They are usually set when your tool chain is configured but you can check them from the Tools > Options dialog. If your includes are not in any of the paths listed, you will have to add the path. Below is an example of my configuration:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Tools->Options->Code Assistance->C++ Compiler->add path C:\MinGW\bin. 
This solved the problem.

Comment: that will probably work if the OP was running MINGW on windows, the she/he was asking about Ubuntu.